# Sharepoint foundation 2010 on mac

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, explorer-view, mac-os-x

Are there any known issues with SPF 2010 on Mac OS X?

Also, will I be able to use the explorer view?

Thank you,
Alkis

Answer (score 3):

There is a browser compatibility overview from Microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288142.aspx

Comment: Thank you Matthias. Do you know about the explorer view?

Comment: Explorer view relies on Active X and windows explorer as do things like DataSheet view - not a chance that will work on non-windows. Its in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

From my cross browser testing for our public site the browsers work well enough with SharePoint and SP1, although the ribbon bar and some of the explorer views tend to be slightly problematic in display.  Often the biggest pain I have found with Safari has been that the page doesn't always update properly on initial load, there is some problem with Safari thinking the page has loaded while some JavaScript is still running in the background, usually this goes away with a refresh of the page.

Explorer View works sometimes, othertimes the controls in the Explorer View have not completely worked for me, and the pageload problem here makes things problematic since some pages do not refresh the properties correctly on page reload.  I have done limited testing with Safari so far since I have more control on what our Users may use when they are given permissions to access the more advanced content controls.

Answer (score 0):

An adequate alternative for Explorer View should be the "Microsoft Document Connection" for Mac. I am not a Mac guy but some of our clients are. Here is a good description how to use it on technet:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10527.sharepoint-work-with-documents-using-document-connection-for-mac-os.aspx